# How to Enable /etc/rc.local with Systemd 18.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

i tried to install /etc/rc.local and i am stuck in this step

[image: terminal pic]

Comment: Please post text and not images. You can do copy&paste from your terminal into the text box for the question.

Comment: i did that already :(

Answer (score 5):

The error you're getting is:

```
Failed to execute command: Exec format error
```

That means systemd is trying to execute `/etc/rc.local` as an executable (for instance, a shell script), but that is failing since it appears the `/etc/rc.local` file is not a valid executable.

Please take a look at its contents. If it's a script, do you have a proper "shebang" line, such as `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning?

Does the file have the "executable" bit set? (You can set it with `chmod +x /etc/rc.local`).

Please edit your answer and include the output of commands `ls -l /etc/rc.local` and `file /etc/rc.local`, which will help identify the exact issue you're having.

---

**UPDATE:** From your comment below, looks like you were missing the shebang line `#!/bin/bash` in your `/etc/rc.local`, adding that line fixed the problem.

Comment: @ChangEtheColours Please post the solution as proper answer. Comments don't allow for extensive formatting, and it's impossible to understand what exactly has been changed in the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl status rc-local
```

**FAILED**

[image: screenshot from terminal]

If I erase from

```
/etc/rc.local  ***the*** 
/usr/bin/garbd --cfg /etc/garbd.conf &
exit 0
```

and save only with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

then I get this

[[image: screenshot from *terminal*]